# What arguments does a c application like snmpget take?

Tags: c, snmp, net-snmp

I want to call `snmpget.c` from another c program in the same project. For that reason I have changed the `main()` into a function say `get_func()` which takes the same arguments. But i an not sure how to give the arguments namely `argv[0]`
My arguments look something like this:

```
char *argstr[]=
{
        "v",
        "1",
        "c",
        "public",
        "-Ovq",
        "192.168.1.1",
        "ifInOctets.7",
        "ifOutOctets.7",
        NULL
};
```

And then

```
i = get_func(10, argstr);
```

1.Should `argv[0]` be the app name or path?

2.Is using `char *argstr[]` correct for c?

3.`snmpget` is not taking these arguments correctly. What could the reason be?

It works correctly with the same args in command.

Comment: @Sathish: If you suggest trivial edits, at least don't make things less correct. And don't touch code!

Comment: A better title would be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your `get_func` expects the arguments starting at `argv[1]`, so your `argstr` argument should not start with `"v"` but with something else (e.g. the programme name or just an empty string if `get_func` doesn’t use it).
2. Yes. But be aware that your `argstr` contains non-modifiable strings, if `get_func` wants to modify them, you can use compound literals

   > ```
   > char *argstr[]=
   > {
   >         (char []){ "v" },
   >         (char []){ "1" },
   >         /* etc */
   >         NULL
   > };
   > ```
3. See 1. and 2. Additionally, `argc` is incorrect (must be `sizeof argstr/sizeof *argstr - 1`, which is 8 in your case, not 10).

---

Not directly an answer to your question, but consider redesigning this (depends on what exactly you’re currently doing, however). For example, write a function accepting a structure where the different options are stored (already parsed and validated) and change the old `main` from **snmpget.c** to a function only scanning and validating arguments, initializing such a structure object, and calling this function. And then, perhaps split your files into **snmpget.c**, **snmpget_main.c**, **another_c_file.c** (with better names, of course) and link both user interface implementations against the object file of **snmpget.c**.

Comment: +1 for compound literals >o< But `argstr` should be `char *argstr[]`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @ikh Thanks! I had problems with the formatting and removed the asterisk and forgot to add it later.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. Just to clarify in point no. 2 if it is supposed to end with a `;` or not.

Comment: Yes, the `;` is needed. Sorry, I should have compiled even this small snippet. It was the second typo. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, if your `main` uses it. If not, just pass `NULL` is enough >o<
2. Sure, it's array of *pointers*. `char *argstr[9]` is equal to

   ```
   typedef char *pchar;
   pchar argstr[9];
   ```
3. Well, I assume you don't give appropriate `argc` and don't pass the app name by `argv[0]` because the `argc` is `10`, but the number of content of `argv` is 8. (I've counted excluding `NULL`, but the `NULL` is required yet - `argv[argc]` should be `NULL`.)
   To reduce mistakes, I suggest to use `sizeof(argstr) / sizeof(argstr[0]) - 1` instead of calculating `argc` yourself.

See [live example](http://ideone.com/FfgwRX). Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int test(int argc, char *argv[]);

int main()
{
    char *argstr[] = {
        "test.exe",
        "--opt-1",
        "--output",
        "test.txt",
        NULL
    };
    int argcount = sizeof(argstr) / sizeof(argstr[0]) - 1;
    return test(argcount, argstr);
}

int test(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;

    printf("argc: %d\n", argc);
    printf("program name: %s\n", argv[0]);
    for (i = 1; argv[i] != NULL; i++)
    {
        printf("argument %d is: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
argc: 4
program name: test.exe
argument 1 is: --opt-1
argument 2 is: --output
argument 3 is: test.txt
```